# bounded linear functional null space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$X$ is a normed linear space.

$f_{0},f_{1},f_{2}...f_{n}$ are bounded linear functional.

$\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}ker(f_{k})\subset ker(f_{0})$

Proof $f_{0}\in span(f_{1},f_{2}...f_{n})$

How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.